# Selecting data in rows based on criteria in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have xls file with two columns which i would like to read in pandas.
Then from dataframe created I would like to output another xls file based on criteria in the column result.

If data in result column equals fail and the output xls file should contain data from 1 row above and 1 row below and data from the fail row itself.

example of input and output shown

input:

```
Team    result
1   pass
2   pass
3   fail
4   pass
5   pass
6   pass
7   fail
8   pass
9   pass
10  pass
11  pass
12  pass
13  pass
14  fail
15  pass
```

output:

```
Team    result
2   pass
3   fail
4   pass
6   pass
7   fail
8   pass
13  pass
14  fail
15  pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a centered [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) sum on the boolean Series deriving from equality to your target ('fail'), and perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df['result'].eq('fail').rolling(3, center=True, min_periods=1).max().eq(1)]
```

*NB. **this makes it easy to select more rows below/after**. For example to get 2 above + 2 below use `5` (2*n+1 for the generic case) as a rolling window.*

output:

```
    Team result
1      2   pass
2      3   fail
3      4   pass
5      6   pass
6      7   fail
7      8   pass
12    13   pass
13    14   fail
14    15   pass
```

Comment: This is brilliant. However, I would like to ask how the `rolling` function works here in particular when the center is set to `True`.

Comment: @Anoushiravan I am not sure what is unclear to you, in short `df['result'].eq('fail')` gives a boolean series (`True`/`False`), `.rolling(3, center=True, min_periods=1).max()` internally converts to `1`/`0` and for each position, assuming a window of `2*n+1`, takes the n rows before and n after (thus **centered** on a given value), computes the `max`. We then convert back to boolean with `eq(1)`. Is this more clear?

Comment: Yes I got it, thank you very much for more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`shift` is your friend here. You will have to shift the `result` column up and down, and keep the row if one of the values is `fail`:

```
x = (df['result'] == 'fail') | (df['result'].shift() == 'fail') | (
     df['result'].shift(-1) == 'fail')
print(df[x])
```

gives as expected:

```
    Team result
1      2   pass
2      3   fail
3      4   pass
5      6   pass
6      7   fail
7      8   pass
12    13   pass
13    14   fail
14    15   pass
```

Comment: Thanks. with this code ,in my output I only seeing data for result column but i need to see the other column Team data  included in output too.

Answer (score 1):

You can add and subtract 1 one from the indexes where `df['result'] == 'fail'` but this can also result in `KeyError` if there is a `fail` on the last row. So we also need to use `index.intersection` to reach valid indexes:

```
all_indexes = np.ravel([df[df['result'] == 'fail'].index + i for i in range(-1, 2)])
valid_indexes = df.index.intersection(all_indexes)
df.loc[valid_indexes]
```

Output:

```
    result
1   pass
2   fail
3   pass
5   pass
6   fail
7   pass
12  pass
13  fail
14  pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    if dd.iloc[1,1]=='fail':
        df1.loc[dd.index,'col1']=True
    return 0

pd.Series(df1.rolling(3,center=True)).apply(function1)\
    .pipe(lambda dd:df1.loc[lambda dd:dd.col1==True,:'result'])

  Team result
1      2   pass
2      3   fail
3      4   pass
5      6   pass
6      7   fail
7      8   pass
12    13   pass
13    14   fail
14    15   pass
```